# How to make custom cypress commands work with typescript

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have set up the following example repo following the example code from the documentation of Cypress both for setting up the project and adding typescript to it to the letter:
https://github.com/jacobdo2/cypress-ts-starter

I add the example command in `commands.ts`:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("dataCy", (id: string) => cy.get(`[data-cy="${id}"]`));
```

and the declaration in `index.ts`:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    /**
     * Custom command to select DOM element by data-cy attribute.
     * @example cy.dataCy('greeting')
     */
    dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>;
  }
}
```

and I get the following error in `index.ts`:
[image]

and in `commands.ts`:

[image]

Comment: If you followed the instructions and they don't work, you need to raise that with the maintainers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try with the following?

```js
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
      dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>;
    }
  }
}
```

You should add the `namespace` inside the `global` declaration. It is working for me correctly.

I am using `Cypress v8.7.0` and Typescript `v4.1.3`.

Comment: That fixed it. There's an error that you get `Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations` and to get rid of that, I needed to add `export {}` somewhere in the index file.

Comment: I am pleased I helped with that!

Comment: Simple solution, should be in the Cypress docs!

Comment: It should, but their docs are the bare minimum they can have to cover simple use cases.

Comment: What is the path of `index.ts`? Is it in the project root?

Comment: @MartijnDirkse I added it at the same level of tsconfig.json that cypress folder has and it worked

Comment: Thanks. I am referencing commands.ts from e2e.ts and hence I do not need index.ts. I wanted to know nevertheless because I used your post to get my project working. I upvoted it and because of that I also wanted to understand it.