# How can I set up custom commands for Cypress with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I started a new project with yarn and added TypeScript and cypress as dependencies. I created an example test with a custom command. The test is in file `cypress/e2e/cypress/example.cy.ts` and reads:

```
describe('Example', () => {
        it('example', () => {
                cy.myCommand();
        })
})
```

The command is in `cypress/e2e/cypress/support/commands.ts` and reads:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('myCommand', () => {
        cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io')
})
```

When I run this in Cypress, my test fails with the following error: "cy.myCommand is not a function". How can I configure my tests correctly?

I am using Cypress 13.6.5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make custom cypress commands work with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995999/how-to-make-custom-cypress-commands-work-with-typescript)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, @agoff. The answer was helpful, but it was not exactly what I wanted. I did not like to introduce `index.ts` because that file was not generated by Cypress like `e2e.ts`. Furthermore I did not know where to put `index.ts`.

Comment: I have upvoted the question you are referring to and the answer it currently has.

Answer (score 2):

When you add cypress and TypeScript as dependencies, you do not automatically have a correct configuration. By combining some similar answers, I found the following solution:

- Rename `cypress/e2e/cypress/support/e2e.js` to `cypress/e2e/cypress/support/e2e.ts`. This file just imports commands.{js|ts}.
- Update `commands.ts` to be as follows:

  ```
  declare namespace Cypress {
      interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
          myCommand(): Chainable<any>;
      }
  }

  Cypress.Commands.add('myCommand', () => {
      cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io')
  })
  ```
- Rename `cypress.config.js` to `cypress.config.ts` (in the root directory of your project).
- Add the following line to `cypress.config.ts`:

  ```
  supportFile: 'cypress/e2e/cypress/support/e2e.ts'
  ```

Comment: Maybe it would strictly be `Chainable<undefined>` since that particular command has no return value and Cypress defaults to `undefined` when you don't make an explicit return, but `Chainable<any>` is a good catch-all.